# Can UDEV somehow trigger zenity for a logged in user in a session?

Tags: linux, usb, udev, zenity

I would like a `zenity` dialog popup to ask me if I would like to run a backup, when I attached a specific external drive.

Unfortunately, I am having trouble with the UDEV rule syntax. I've got this rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/test.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Western Digital", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1058", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1140", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/test.sh"
```

It's pretty basic, but:

1. It gets triggered a dozen times in stead of once.
2. It cannot 'speak' using `zenity` when `test.sh` goes `sudo -Hu <username> zenity --warning --text="Just some random text for now."` because udev is tucked away in the system and cannot find the window manager: *Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:*
3. It's not very edit-friendly, I wish there were some kind of rule where I can just type the LABEL for certain partitions on which I would like to trigger certain scripts.

I would like to see a general improvement for the UDEV rule, because apart from the many questions and answers about it, here and elsewhere, they all seem a bit different from each other and most of them trigger multiple times.

But most importantly, how, in any way, can I make the connection from here to a script in my home that has access to stuff like my session and my screen so that `zenity` can work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already found the answer. The script (zenity) needs an X Window Server for displaying a message. The script is run from `udev` and has no display attached to it. You can solve this by hardwiring the `DISPLAY` variable in your script, i.e.

```
DISPLAY=:0; export DISPLAY
```

The drawback to this is, it works only, if you are the only user and/or know the display in advance. If there are multiple users on your system, the display might be anything else, for example `:1`, `:2`, and so on. Or another users gets the zenity message on his screen.

A better approach would be to split the detection of the event and the interaction with the user or display of the message.

For this you can create a script or program, which runs in your GUI session and listens for a trigger from a daemon or the udev trigger script.

A third possibility could be to connect to the `udisks-daemon` and ask for information, when the external device is plugged in. You can try [`udisks --monitor`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/udisks) or `udisks --monitor-detail` for this and parse the output, whenever an event happens.

There seems to be a [`udisksctl`](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/udisksctl.1.html) command, which does the same with a slightly different syntax. Maybe it's just a newer version of the `udisks` command.

You can also look at some Gui tools like [GNOME Disks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks), which rely on the udev/udisks system as well.

**Update**:

The multiple invocations usually arise from the report of the various subsystems. You can see that, when you log the environment to some log file in the `/usr/local/bin/test.sh` script

```
umask 077
mkdir -p /tmp/udevtest.d
env >>/tmp/udevtest.d/udevtest.log
```

When I plugin a USB stick, I get the following reports

```
$ grep -e ACTION -e SUBSYSTEM /tmp/udevtest.d/udevtest.log
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=scsi
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_host
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=scsi
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=scsi
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_disk
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_generic
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_device
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=bsg
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=block
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=block
```

You can also add `DEVTYPE` to distinguish between the two `usb` or `disk` reports.
So, in order to reduce the reports to just a few or even only one call, you must be more specific and add additional conditions to your udev rules file, for example choose the `SUBSYSTEM=scsi_disk` or whatever is appropriate for your device.

Comment: Thank you for the response and mentioning alternatives. You were right, `DISPLAY=:0` did the trick. This answer addressess subquestion 2, but as subquestion 1 predicted, I now get my `zenity` popup about 30 times for 1 plugged in drive. Any idea how I can tone this down? Preferably I would like the script to be called with just the partition name as argument. (E.g. script is called 3 times with 3 partitions.)

I also tried `udisks` because it seems so easy, but it just sits there claiming to be monitoring, but not reporting anything I plug in. Maybe it's not implemented correctly for Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah `udiskctl` does monitor events. I will look into it further if I can't figure out how to do it in the `udev` rules as initially planned.

Comment: @Redsandro Please see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. It's still a puzzle, but I'm better informed now. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody else reading this, the only way I was able to get my script in Kali Linux 2016 to work, was like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
xhost local:root
export DISPLAY=:0.0
su root -c 'zenity --notification --text="I am a notification!"'
```